# Can I convert an HTML date picker to a Hijri calendar format?

Tags: html, date, html-input, hijri

I have a small MVC 5 application which uses Arabic culture settings. I have a DateTime property in my model from this Razor syntax:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate)
```

This `DateTime` control appears on the form like this:

[image: standard HTML date picker]

I need to convert this control to a Hijri format, is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

The control rendered is a standard [HTML5 `input` with type `date`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html).

I have seen some [bug reports](http://t6503.org-w3c-html-public.w3ctalk.info/input-type-date-hijri-t6503.html) on the availability on globalization and the lack of other than Gregorian calendars. However, this is not something incorporated in the standard, it should be implemented in the browser:

> The user interface is left up to the UA, so browsers are encouraged to 
>   provide such user options if it makes sense for their users' locale. (The 
>   submission format is always Gregorian, though.)

So as long as your browser supports the Hijri calendar (and you have the correct regional settings), you can use it. Otherwise you can't, and you should use another control that supports the calendar and write it back to an `input` with type `text`.